# Unable to debug a ResourceNotFoundException

Tags: java, android

I'm having a little trouble trying to debug a `Resources$NotFoundException`. I'm trying to add items from an enum to a `AlertDialog` dynamically:

Here's the code from my `Activity`:

```
final ArrayList<CharSequence> lstChoices = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();

for (TrendingManager.Filter fltFilter : TrendingManager.Filter.values()) {

    lstChoices
    .add(getResources()
            .getString(
                    getApplicationContext()
                            .getResources()
                            .getIdentifier(
                                    fltFilter.name().toLowerCase(),
                                    "string",
                                    getApplicationContext()
                                            .getApplicationInfo().packageName)));

}
```

Here's the list of enums:

```
public class TrendingManager {

    public static enum Filter {
            ONLY_PRIVATE, ONLY_PUBLIC, ONLY_HQ, ONLY_LQ
    };

}
```

I have all those 4 enums defined in my `strings.xml` and it works on my phone but I get crash reports from a user's phone which says:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:260)
at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:344)
at com.mridang.myapp.Trend.onOptionsItemSelected(Trend.java:230)
at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2564)
...
...
...
```

I'm really lost with as to why this happens. Any ideas as to why the resource isn't found?

Answer (score 3):

You should really split the statement in the loop in to several statements which do exactly one thing.

This way you will better see where your problem is.

Comment: Running the code locally on my emulator or my phone doesn't raise the the exception.

Comment: You should have written this in your question. Have you checked that `strings.xml` is included in the package?

Comment: It seems to be. I used the APK that I had uploaded to the Play Store and ran APKTool on it to decompile it. I found the `strings.xml` in it and those strings existed in the file. I installed that APK n my phone and even that worked just fine.